# Use of DTLS (Datagram Transport Layer Security) with SNMP and Management Systems

Tags: security, snmp, nms, dtls

Does anyone know if the current crop of SNMP based commercial and open source network management systems (eg, HP OpeenView/NNM, OpenNMS) support the use of SNMP over [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347)?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to OpenView, OpenNMS, etc.: I'm not sure.

I do know that Net-SNMP does not yet support this, but it is in the works.

This is from the Net-SNMP coders mailing list. I ran into an issue with v3 thread-safeness and received this reply.

> Wes Hardaker:
>
> The SNMPv3 support in Net-SNMP isn't, unfortunately, thread-safe.  We
>   think/hope that the replacement DTLS/TLS support coming out in a future
>   release will make it thread-safe when used over DTLS though.

Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks. We've actually had some discussions with the NetSNMP folks, they seem to be further along than anyone else.  Remains to be seen as to when vendors will actually support it.